# String thrown as a Custom Exception appearing weird in SOAPUI?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, exception, soapui

I am trying to throw a custom exception in SOAP UI. For example,

```
throw new CustomException(String message, FaultObject faultObject);
```

Ideally, I need both message and the fault object to appear in the SOAPUI as soap fault. That is, I want the message that is defined as custom fault(shown below after the !CDATA) and all parameters inside it. However, when I am throwing the custom exception, I am getting the following response. Any suggestions as to how to correct fault message. In my wsdl, I have defined the fault message, and I am throwing the same fault message that was generated from the stubs. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. If you need more info, please let me know.

```
 xml:lang="en"><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><ns2:CustomFault xmlns:ns2="http:test" xmlns="http:test1"><ns2:Message>Number='',Version='',Message='Invalid Data'</ns2:Message><ns2:Errors><ns2:Error><ns2:ErrorSource>dd</ns2:ErrorSource><ns2:ErrorNumber>12</ns2:ErrorNumber><ns2:ErrorCode>2501</ns2:ErrorCode><ns2:ErrorMessage>Date failed</ns2:ErrorMessage></ns2:Error></ns2:Errors></ns2:CustomFault>]]>
```

Comment: SOAPUI can not interpret your custom message as a SOAPFault, the `<Fault>` is an element defined in the `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/`, your `<CustomFault>` is not form this type, and soapui interprets this as a valid response. If you need a soap fault, then you must return a `<Fault xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">`.